# How to find distance between class representation's decision boundaries for a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, classification, knowledge-representation

I have a 5 layer DNN with data containing 10 classes. To study how the model works, one thing among many I am looking at is the class wise representations.
I can extract the representations of each class from the 3rd and/or penultimate layer of the DNN, but how do I find the distance between these representations in the representation space ?
I want to look at decision boundaries and find the minimal distance between each class's boundary to another, but am stuck on how to do this.

I looked at t-SNE plots, where I can feed each class representation as a vector. But this does not include decision boundaries.

Why am I fixed on including decision boundary ? If given 2 models, I want to find how well each of the models separate the representation of one classes from the others.

Comment: How exactly are you computing the "representations of each class"? Can you provide more details of what they also look like?